# why find method return -1 in python if str is not found

Tags: python, methods, find

I am a python beginner.
In `str.find(sub)` method, this find method return `-1` if `sub` is not found.
I want to know why return `-1` instead of `0`, `1` or other numbers or Nonetype.
Why of all things, `-1` is returned?

Comment: It probably just calls some underlying C function that returns -1 for not found.  Since Python is written in C, a lot of the conventions are derived from it.

Answer (score 0):

In python the strings are 0 indexed meaning the first element of the variable name is accessed by `var_name[0]`. Returning 0 would mean the string has been found starting at location 0. Whereas a -1 tells us that it hasn't been found.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question! I understand strings are indexed by integers. But why should -1  be returned? Is there any intentions using such way?

Answer (score 0):

A string is just an array of characters. the method `find` will return the first index in the array (string) that do matches. Arrays start at `0` where zero is the first item in the array (string). `-1` is just to represent `Not Found` and avoid confusion with index `0` (or anything greater than zero)

Comment: Thank you for answering my question!! I understand -1 is just to represent Not Found.  
But  i  wonder there is any way to use that '-1' in python?

Comment: Other than "just by convention", no idea honestly. You could ask the devs in the main Python repo.

Answer (score -1):

I had this exact same question and i have what i felt was a satisfying answer.

first off think of this, any integer can be written over 1 and its still the same number. 3 == 3/1

with that in mind, think of the -1 return as equivalent too 'string[-1:]'
if executed as a print command, it returns nothing.
that is print(string[-1:-1])
prints:          (nothing) lol